# How to if "x" match any of an array

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to know how to write in bash an if statement with select command that echo a prompt error in case non correct option is given.

"The $strings variable is a column of strings."

```
menu() {

strings=$(echo "$(awk -F'[][]' '{ print $(2) }' file | awk NF)")

    select string in $strings
        do
            if [[ "$string" MATCH ANY "${strings[@]}" ]]
                then
                    echo "you've selected $account"
                    break
                else
                    echo "Please, select one of the given options." && sleep 2
                    clear && menu
            fi
        done
}
```

I tried with:

```
if [[ "$string" =~ "${strings[@]} ]]
```

But does not work.
Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no "match any" operator. Use a loop or associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was as easy as not trying to compare with anything else, like this:

```
menu() {

    strings=$(echo "$(awk -F'[][]' '{ print $(2) }' file | awk NF)")

    select string in $strings
    do
        if [[ "$string" ]]
            then
                echo "you've selected $account"
                break
            else
                echo "Please, select one of the given options." && sleep 2
                clear && menu
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are missing the closing quote on your if.
it should be:

```
if [[ "$string" =~ "${strings[@]}" ]]
```

Comment: Hi @benjamin ,
yes, I forgot to type it here but I have it in my code and doesn't work...

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: `strings` is not an array.